# Is it possible to run bsc node with minimal config (especially low disk storage)?

Tags: nodes, bsc

I have a vps with 8vCPU, 16GB RAM and 160GB SSD. Is it possible to setup a bsc mainet node even if the official documentation (https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html#fullnodes-functions) got way higher minimal config.

I might try anyway but i've never set up a node and wanted to know if it was dumb to even try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you from experience that no, you can't.

First, you need more than 160Gb. You need 500Gb at the very least to complete a fast sync, but 1TB makes more sense if you don't want to resync from scratch all the time.

Also, many people have syncing problems with SATA SSD and you likely need a good M.2 NVMe SSD.

Comment: Oh thanks, is it long to resync every time from scratch cause i could have access to 500GB but 1TB will be hard as my vps provider doesnt propose such high storage...

Comment: I don't remember how long it took last time I did it. Probably in the range of 24h-48h. However, I have a very fast NVMe SSD (samsung 980 Pro) and a slower SSD could take more time.

Comment: Right, so it's definetly not a solution for me. I just saw https://docs.binance.org/fullnode.html displayed lesser requirements that i could meet with a little upgrade, any chance you know why the requierments are different than the other tutorial i linked ?

Comment: Your link points to the requirements of Binance Chain, not Binance SMART Chain (two different blockchains). Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: yes didnt saw that, i accepted it, didn't knew you could even do that ahah, thanks have a great day